# (Delphi) Trying to make derivative DBGrid, can't make it work

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

For certain reasons I can't use additional components such as EhLib or DevExpress QuantumGrid, so I'm trying to make my own component, derivative from standard DBGrid.

But I don't have enough in-depth knowledge of Delphi, and thus tried to use example from
http://etutorials.org/Programming/mastering+delphi+7/Part+III+Delphi+Database-Oriented+Architectures/Chapter+17+Writing+Database+Components/Customizing+the+DBGrid+Component/
("Mastering Delphi" by Marco Cantu)

But... It acts like a standard DBgrid, no word wrap happening.

**Edit**: okay, looks like I've found the source of the problem. Don't know what to do with it, though. Though Canvas draws on the form, it draws under it's elements. It seems to does draw what I want, but I can't see it! I checked it by drawing a simple rectangle in `OnDrawColumn` event and moved `PageControl` up and down to check.

**Edit2**: sorry for testing your patience, Tom Brunberg, and here is the code (also I have uploaded the files at https://www.dropbox.com/sh/971w8r3wz62zcfg/AAD5knqO5FJg-a9SGqCtY8mPa?dl=0).

**Edit3**: thank you so much Tom Brunberg for your help! Unsetting `DefaultDrawing` and adding additional fields `TWideStringField` and `TWideMemoField` helped!

```
unit MdDbGrid;

interface

uses
  SysUtils, WinTypes, WinProcs, Messages, Classes, Graphics, Controls,
  Forms, Dialogs, DB, StdCtrls, ExtCtrls, Grids, DBGrids;

type
  TMdDbGrid = class(TDBGrid)
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FLinesPerRow: Integer;
    procedure SetLinesPerRow (Value: Integer);
  protected
    { Protected declarations }
    procedure DrawColumnCell(const Rect: TRect; DataCol: Integer;
      Column: TColumn; State: TGridDrawState); override;
    procedure  LayoutChanged; override;
  public
    { Public declarations }
    constructor Create (AOwner: TComponent); override;
  published
    { Published declarations }
    property LinesPerRow: Integer
      read FLinesPerRow write SetLinesPerRow default 1;
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('MyComponents', [TMdDbGrid]);
end;

constructor TMdDbGrid.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  FLinesPerRow:=1;
end;

procedure TMdDbGrid.SetLinesPerRow(Value: Integer);
begin
  if Value <> FLinesPerRow then
  begin
    FLinesPerRow := Value;
    LayoutChanged;
  end;
end;

procedure TMdDbGrid.LayOutChanged;
var
  PixelsPerRow, PixelsTitle, I: Integer;
begin
  inherited LayOutChanged;

  Canvas.Font := Font;
  PixelsPerRow := Canvas.TextHeight('Wg') + 3;
  if dgRowLines in Options then
    Inc (PixelsPerRow, GridLineWidth);

  Canvas.Font := TitleFont;
  PixelsTitle := Canvas.TextHeight('Wg') + 4;
  if dgRowLines in Options then
    Inc (PixelsTitle, GridLineWidth);

  // set number of rows
  RowCount := 1 + (Height - PixelsTitle) div (PixelsPerRow * FLinesPerRow);

  // set the height of each row
  DefaultRowHeight := PixelsPerRow * FLinesPerRow;
  RowHeights [0] := PixelsTitle;
  for I := 1 to RowCount - 1 do
    RowHeights [I] := PixelsPerRow * FLinesPerRow;

  // send a WM_SIZE message to let the base component recompute
  // the visible rows in the private UpdateRowCount method
  PostMessage (Handle, WM_SIZE, 0, MakeLong(Width, Height));
end;

procedure TMdDbGrid.DrawColumnCell (const Rect: TRect; DataCol: Integer;
  Column: TColumn; State: TGridDrawState);
var
  Bmp: TBitmap;
  OutRect: TRect;
begin
  if FLinesPerRow = 1 then
    inherited DrawColumnCell(Rect, DataCol, Column, State)
  else
  begin
    // clear area
    //Canvas.FillRect (Rect);
    Self.Canvas.FillRect (Rect);

    // Annd... This is where I discovered that the program is already not working as it should.
    // Canvas.FillRect was supposed to draw filled squares over data cells, over which new text would be drawn
    // I commented out the executable code that was supposed to draw the text.
    //The result should have been empty cells on the new grid. But the grid was still drawn as a single line with the same text.


    // copy the rectangle
    OutRect := Rect;
    // restrict output
    InflateRect (OutRect, -2, -2);
    // output field data
    if Column.Field is TGraphicField then
    begin
      Bmp := TBitmap.Create;
      try
        Bmp.Assign (Column.Field);
        Canvas.StretchDraw (OutRect, Bmp);
      finally
        Bmp.Free;
      end;
    end
    else if (Column.Field is TMemoField) or (Column.Field is TWideStringField) or (Column.Field is TWideMemoField) then
    begin 
      DrawText (Canvas.Handle, PChar (Column.Field.AsString),
        Length (Column.Field.AsString), OutRect, dt_WordBreak or dt_NoPrefix)
    end
    else // draw single line vertically centered
      DrawText (Canvas.Handle, PChar (Column.Field.DisplayText),
        Length (Column.Field.DisplayText), OutRect,
        dt_vcenter or dt_SingleLine or dt_NoPrefix); 
  end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: It is practically impossible to say for certain what you have done wrong, as you don't show your implementation and usage. A wild guess is that the column/field that should have multiple lines capability is not defined as a `TMemoField`. Please show your *complete* code.

Comment: You say: *Okay, looks like I've found the source of the problem.* Great! But why don't you tell us **what it is** and **where it is**? We don't see your computer screen! I really don't like to repeat myself, but if you want help, **please show *your* code**.

Comment: So, news from the fields. It looks like Canvas in this code works with Form, rather than the grid. Are there any ways to adress the exemplar of the class like using keyword "this" in C#?

Comment: Found it, "self". And no, result is still the same. What. The. Hell.

Comment: As I said in my first comment, I suspect that the field that is intended to have several lines, is not defined to be a `TMemoField`. As the code says: `else if Column.Field is TMemoField ...` it is the condition for multiline output with `DrawText()`.

Comment: The other point you claim that the expected blank cells show single line text even though you outcommented painting/drawing commands in `DrawColumnCell`, has a natural explanation in that probably you did not unset `DefaultDrawing` property, which is set as default. Of course, this is only a guess on my side as you did not post your `.dfm` file.

Comment: I made a test project based on your code and and my corrections as in above comments and it does show multiline output for `TMemoField` content.

Comment: Thank you so much, Tom Brunberg, your advice really worked. And now a bit more difficult task - to make program calculate "LinesPerRow" property individually and for each row. Please could you give me advice on how (and where in the code) it could be implemented? I'm sick, and feeling myself absolutely dumb now.

Comment: "A bit" was an irony, to make it clear. I'm thinking that there probably should be an array in the "TMdDbGrid" to store values for each row... Probably rather large, because i'm terrified to think of trying to make it dynamic here... Where is the best place to calculate height, and is that even possible? Won't rows have the wrong height when navigating the grid?

Comment: You should review the [help] for this site, especially [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking), and note that one question post should ask only one question. You asked the question how to correctly implement the code published by Marco Cantú, and you got an answer (although in a comment). The new question, how to apply grid rows of different height (as required by different amount of text data per record), is a new question. So, please post it as a new question. If you think it is beneficial for your new question, you can add a link to this question in the new one.

Comment: A side note, regarding the new task: You need to be clear about what to do with different amount of text in different columns, and also remembering that there is only a single set of rows (the visible ones) in the grid, so you need to dynamically recalculate the required size for each cell and choose the height of each row that scrolls into view.

Comment: I was just asking for directions for future attempts to make it - it looks like I won't have time to resume this topic anytime soon. Much appreciated for your help.